# Xml Serializing and Writer

Tags: c#, xml, streamwriter

in one class I create with a button click a XML document:

```
    private void buttonCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderElg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBoxPath.Text = folderElg.SelectedPath;
            userConfigurePath = folderElg.SelectedPath;
        }
        XmlDocument toolConfig = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode myRoot;                               
        myRoot = toolConfig.CreateElement("Tool");    
        toolConfig.AppendChild(myRoot);
        toolConfig.Save(@userConfigurePath + "\\config.xml");}
```

There I haven't problems. The folder is created and the xml file also.

So in an other class I want to serialize objects into the xml file 'config.xml' (The variable userConfigurePath is static in the classe mentionned above):

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    private string inputNewTool = "";
    private OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();      

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputDialog input = new InputDialog();
        input.ShowDialog();
        inputNewTool = input.enteredTxt;

        if (inputNewTool != null)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Chose the Tool's directory");
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Tool tool = new Tool();
                tool.Name = inputNewTool;
                tool.Path = dlg.FileName;
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(tool.GetType());
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@Start.userConfigurePath + 
                "\\config.xml");
                serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, tool);
            }

        }
```

The result is that the object isn't saved in the config.xml file. Why?

Edit the Tool's Class:

```
 public class Tool
{
    public   string Name { get; set; }
    public   string Path { get; set; }

   public Tool() { }
}
```

Second Edit:

I see that i can't delete manuel these folder (after the application is closed) with the xml file when it is created. Why?

Third Edit:

I changed my Code so:

```
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Tool tool = new Tool();
                tool.Name = inputNewTool;
                tool.Path = dlg.FileName;
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(tool.GetType());
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@Start.userConfigurePath + 
                "\\config.xml"))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, tool);
                    writer.Close();
                }
```

Now the first object is serialized. But if i create another tool in the same way the config.xml doesn't take it. Only the first tool is serialized:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tool xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Name>dffss</Name>
<Path>D:\Users\xxxx\Documents\schulewochenbericht.txt</Path>
</Tool>
```

Comment: What do you mean `object isn't saved in the config.xml`? Do you get an error? or Do you get an unexpected output?

Comment: If I open the xml file there isn't the object with his name and path

Comment: Is your Tool class marked with serializable attribute?

Comment: public   string Name { get; set; }
  public   string Path { get; set;

Comment: @rageit `serializable` is required by *BinaryFormatter*, no need when using  *XmlSerializer*

Comment: Please include the `Tool` class source to the question.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Your serialization code works fine with a valid path.

Comment: no errors. Maybe there is an error for this assignement?:textBoxPath.Text = folderElg.SelectedPath;
            userConfigurePath = folderElg.SelectedPath;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close the StreamWriter object to flush the data into the file.  Please try the following:

```
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(tool.GetType());
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@Start.userConfigurePath + "\\config.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, tool);
            }
```

Comment: hm there isn't a change in the result

Comment: Verify that `@Start.userConfigurePath` contains the right path to the config.xml file.

Comment: Contain the right path :( Do you need more information? Then I will add them to the mai npost

Comment: What gets written to the `config.xml` file?

Comment: the serialization of the tool object

Comment: So, what's missing there?  can you share the `config.xml` content after running the serialization code above?

Comment: ?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tool xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from wdosanjos, you should also realize that you can't just write a sequence of `Tool` objects. If you want to write more than one `Tool`, then you need to write an array or list of `Tool`.