# List XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization

I create a list where the user creates an object which will be added to the list.

```
private List<Tool> toolList = new List<Tool>();

private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputDialog input = new InputDialog();
        input.ShowDialog();
        inputNewTool = input.enteredTxt;

        if (inputNewTool != null)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Chose the Tool's directory");
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".exe";
            dlg.Filter = "Application (.exe)|*.exe";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Tool tool = new Tool();
                tool.Name = inputNewTool;
                tool.Path = dlg.FileName;
                toolList.Add(tool);
                comboBoxTools.Items.Add(tool.Name);
            }
        }
```

Prior to this the application draws up a folder with a XML File:

```
 private void buttonCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderElg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBoxPath.Text = folderElg.SelectedPath;
            userConfigurePath = folderElg.SelectedPath;
        }
        XmlDocument toolConfig = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode myRoot;
        myRoot = toolConfig.CreateElement("Tool");
        toolConfig.AppendChild(myRoot);
        toolConfig.Save(@userConfigurePath + "\\config.xml");

    }
```

If the user creates multiple objects they are in the list. That I verified. These objects should be serialized:

```
    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Tool t in toolList)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType(), new 
            XmlRootAttribute("Tools"));
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@Start.userConfigurePath + 
            "\\config.xml")) 
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, t);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

No matter how many objects are in the list in the XML File is only the last object serialized:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tool xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Name>zest6</Name>
<Path>C:\Program Files\FreePDF_XP\fpsetup.exe</Path>
</Tool>
```

Why the last serialized objects overwrites the others?

Comment: Serialize `toolList` not `t`. BTW: No reason to use `writer.BaseStream`, just use `writer`

Comment: Also see *John Saunders*' answer in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703811/xml-serializing-and-writer), where you wrote *I guessed this* :)

Comment: You're right. I didn't know how I can serialize a complete List. Sometimes it is to obvious to understand sorry